# Forcing Codiqa To Honor Select Box Size Attribute

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, codiqa

I have also posted this question to Codiqa support some time ago, so I am not trying to turn stackoverflow into a Codiqa support center, just know alot of the guys supporting Codiqa are on here, but let me know if I am not allowed to be asking for support for a product on this site...

That aside, I have a select box with size="5" attribute that displays a max of 5 options that are populated via for loop with information from a database. The idea is for this select box to act as a listbox to show the user said information in the select box. However, Codiqa or maybe jquery mobile in general, converts any select box into a button that only can view the content when clicked on. This adds an extra and unnecessary step for my client in this instance. How can I force Codiqa or jquery mobile to honor my size attribute, so the user can see the populated information without having to click to view?

Thank you!

Chrome Browser

[image]

Codiqa

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of Codiqa here. This is jQuery Mobile behavior that you can disable by telling it to not enhance that form element:

```
<label for="foo">
<select name="foo" id="foo" size="5" data-role="none">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

We don't have a way to do this right inside of Codiqa yet, but it would be easy enough to add.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't cut it. I have <td><select name="lead2_cabletypes" id="lead2_cabletypes" size="5" data-role="none"></select></td> (options are created dynamically using js for loop) I am using PhoneGap as well, same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334357/why-does-size-property-doesnt-shows-up-multiple-options-like-a-list-box-on-a So maybe this is not really a Codiqa issue?

Comment: In that case it might not be a jQuery Mobile issue at all, could be a browser limitation on those devices. Might want to find a plugin that does this through Javascript. You could also just use a ListView!

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bagz8/

You can programatically force select to open itself when page is available:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $( "#select-choice-4" ).selectmenu( "open" );
});
```

This would be a workaround.

**EDIT :**

Then force jQuery Mobile not to style select boxes. There are several solutions but this one is probably the best: http://jsfiddle.net/bagz8/1/

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select";
});
```

Warning, **`mobileinit`** event MUST be initialized before jQuery Mobile is loaded. You can see it in my example.

There are several other solutions of enhancement prevention and you can find theme [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417), just look for a chapter: **`Methods of markup enhancement prevention`**

Comment: That's a good work around, but issue is I have 5 list boxes with potentially 5 options within each one. That is a bit popup overload ha

Comment: Take a look also at my other solution. You will also find a link about other methods of enhancement prevention with jQuery Mobile.